# Ошибка на ML.NET Время обучения завершено без обученных моделей

Tags: c#, .net, искусственный-интеллект

Пробую добавить в проект МЛ в Visual Studio 2019 Community.
ПКМ / Добавить / Машинное обучение 
Сценарий: Классификация текста 
Среда обучения Локально i7-8800к
Данные: Пробовал и свои данные и скачивал из интернета базу твитов вот пример

```
570013523650048002,neutral,1.0,,,Virgin America,,papamurat,,0,@VirginAmerica are flights leaving Dallas for Seattle on time Feb 24?,,2015-02-23 16:13:09 -0800,,
570012257549070337,positive,1.0,,,Virgin America,,arieldaie,,0,@VirginAmerica I'm #elevategold for a good reason: you rock!!,,2015-02-23 16:08:07 -0800,Los Angeles,
```

Обучение запускается а потом вылетает вот такая ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить? Прост видел видео с конференции там без бубнов все работало сразу, а у меня не хочет.

Comment: Код покажете?..

Comment: Кода нет, делаю по этому гайду https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/machine-learning/automate-training-with-model-builder